# Slick slider - conditional slide navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I managed to style / show my slider navigation with using:

```
$('.next-button-slick').click(function(){
$('.accmd-slides').slick("slickNext");
});
$('.prev-button-slick').click(function(){
$('.accmd-slides').slick("slickPrev");
});
```

The idea is to customize the navigation using Font Awesome icons, but is there a way for me to disable / change the styling of navigation arrows if there is no Next or Previous slide in the slider?

Thank you for helping me out

Comment: Please use JsFiddle for example

Answer (score 0):

if there is no Next or Previous slide, it should be the first slide or the last slide. so it's simple, you change styling in first slide or last slide.

you need to use `afterChange` event, this event is triggered when slide changes. In this event, you can change styling of navigation arrows when the current slide is the first or the last.

```
$('.multiple-items').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    var slickItem = $('.multiple-items .slick-slide:not(".slick-cloned")').length;

  if (currentSlide == 0) {
    //do stuff
    alert('first');
  }
  else if (currentSlide == (slickItem - 1)) {
    //do stuff
    alert('last');
  }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/oedp1L5g/).